# Error moving uploaded file php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I try to add image loading to my site, but it gives me error. Here's result of working php:

> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\php9664.tmp
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(/img/collection/usbwebserver.exe): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Home\Volodya\Projects\Web\CollectionSite\site\php\collection.php on line 26
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\php9664.tmp' to '/img/collection/usbwebserver.exe' in D:\Home\Volodya\Projects\Web\CollectionSite\site\php\collection.php on line 26

Her's my code:
a form:

```
echo ('
    <form action="collection.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <legend>Add coin</legend>
        <select name="countryId">
');     

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultCountry)>0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCountry)) {
        echo("<option value=".$row['country_id'].">".$row['country_name']."</option>");
    }
}

echo('
        </select>
        <select name="curencyId">
');

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultCurency)>0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCurency)) {
        echo("
            <option value=".$row['curency_id'].">".$row['curency_name']."</option>
        ");
    }
}

echo('
    </select>
    <select name="metalId">
');

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultMetal)>0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultMetal)) {
        echo("
            <option value=".$row['metal_id'].">".$row['metal_name']."</option>
        ");
    }
}

echo('
        </select>
        <select name="nominalId">
');

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultNominal)>0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNominal)) {
        echo("
            <option value=".$row['nominal_id'].">".$row['nominal_name']."</option>
        ");
    }
}

echo('
        </select>
        <input type="date" name="dateCreation">
        <input type="number" name="weight">
        <input type="number" name="mintage">
        <input type="file" name="img">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="addcoin">
        <input type="submit" value="Add coin">
    </form>               
');
```

And a code of coping files:

```
echo($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], "/img/collection/".basename($_FILES['img']['name']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to store your images in the root directory of your disk.

Try to prefix the filepath with `__dir__` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Ex:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 
    __dir__ . "/img/collection/".basename($_FILES['img']['name'])) ;
```

**EDIT**  after comments below :

```
00000000  63 6f e2 80 8c e2 80 8b  6c 6c 65 63 74 69 6f 6e  |co......llection|
00000010  20 0a 63 6f e2 80 8c e2  80 8c e2 80 8b e2 80 8b  | .co............|
00000020  6c 6c 65 63 74 69 6f 6e                           |llection|
```

Comment: I did it, but now it returns Unable to move 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\phpCBCD.tmp' to 'D:\Home\Volodya\Projects\Web\CollectionSite\site\php\img\collection\usbwebserver.exe'

Comment: @Poseydon42 What's the path you want to store uploaded files ? Does the folder exists ?

Comment: D:\Home\Volodya\Projects\Web\CollectionSite\site\php\img\co‌​llection\ this path exists.

Comment: @Poseydon42 : It seems `co‌​llection` and `co‌‌​​llection` are not the same. If you copy the two path above in a text editor, the first is 12 chars length, and the second is 14 chars length. Maybe a special char... See the updated anwser.

Comment: I tried to cope it to another dir, there aren't any errors now, but there aren't a file in target directory.

Comment: @Poseydon42 Did you check what `move_uploaded_file()` returns?

Comment: @Poseydon42 I suggest you to check your Apache logs, PHP logs, Folders rights, and add `var_dump()` everywhere you can. Finally, try to ask another question with the problem. I can't do more in this comments. Please consider that the initial question is solved or helps you. Many thanks.